Using a posterior distribution for p and MLE, how do I work out the probability of observing zero rabbits, given its not extinct?
So this question involves assessing the probability that a rabbit is present / not extinct but was not detected during the survey, given the detection probability $p$. From my previous working out, the maximum likelihood estimate of $p$ is:
$$
\hat{p} = \frac{1}{nN} \sum_{i=1}^{n} l_i
$$
The posterior distribution is:
$$
\pi(p \mid \mathbf{l}, N) \sim \text{Beta}(\alpha', \beta')
$$
given $N$ is the total number of rabbits (if present) and the probabilty of not detecting a single rabbit on a survey day is $1-p$.
where the parameters are:
$$
\alpha' = 31.5
$$
$$
\beta' = 271
$$
$$
N=300
$$
$n$ is the $n$ surveyed and $N$ is the total number of rabbits. $p$ is the probability that a single rabbit is spotted on a single day and each observation is independent.
How do I work out the probability of observing zero rabbits, given its not extinct?

You ask for "the probability of observing zero rabbits, given its not extinct" which is unclear to me.  Is this the posterior probability of not seeing any of the $300$ rabbits on a particular future day? Or of not seeing any of the $300$ rabbits on $n$ future days? Or of not seeing a particular rabbits on a particular future day? Or of not seeing a particular rabbits on $n$ future days?  Or is it about the past days?

the context is that the question is about a rabbit survey to detect whether these rabbits are locally extinct. So, p is the probability that a single probability that single rabbit is spotted on a single n day out of a N population of total rabbits. The N would be the number rabbits that could be observed if all them could be.

I am still not totally clear about what you are trying to do, but your model suggests:

The probability of seeing a particular rabbit on a particular day is $p$
The probability of not seeing a particular rabbit on a particular day is $1-p$
The probability of not seeing any of $N$ rabbits on a particular day  is $(1-p)^N$ assuming independence and identical distributions between rabbits
The probability of not seeing a particular rabbit on any of $n$ days is $(1-p)^n$ assuming independence and identical distributions between days
The probability of not seeing any of $N$ rabbits on any of $n$ days is $(1-p)^{nN}$ ...
The expected number of rabbits not seen on any of $n$ days is $N(1-p)^n$ ...

though all these assume that $p$ is fixed.  In fact you have a posterior Beta distribution for $p$ so may want to integrate these expressions over that distribution.
One thing that worries me is that you say you are trying to detect whether these rabbits are locally extinct.  It makes me wonder how you got the parameters for the posterior Beta distribution without actually observing some of these rabbits and so knowing they are not extinct.

Oh, the parameters were computed using Bayes. the question gives $\alpha=1.5$ and $\beta=1.5$ and that on the first day, $l_1=30$ and N=300.
So I calculated the following:
Total Observed Kangaroos: $S = l_1 = 30$
Total Possible Sightings: $T = nN = 1* 300 = 300$
Total non-observed kangaroos: $T-S = 300-30 = 270$

This was substituted into a posterior of $p$ given $l$ and $N$, where $\alpha = \Sigma_{i=1}^n l_i + \alpha $ and $\beta = nN- \Sigma_{i=1}^n + \beta $
